# What causes nvidia driver crash / black screen freeze?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card

I have this problem where I get a black screen for a few seconds and then the game comes back and continues like nothing happened. Things are usually messed up on the desktop when I exit the game like the taskbar is stretched across three screens, or accelerated graphics visual gitches you can tell there's been a driver crash.

This seems to only affect fullscreen games, as opposed to windowed/borderless windowed games.

I'd like to keep fullscreen for some older games that don't support borderless window and which don't work with those borderless window tools due to nvidia surround.

My specs for reference: Intel Core i7 2600K @4.8GHz OC / DeepCool GAMMAX    400 CPU Cooler / ASUS P8Z68-V / Corsair Vengeance 16GB DDR3 @1600Mhz OC MEM / 240GB SSD / Gigabyte G1 Gaming NVIDIA GTX 980 Ti 6GB / 3x Benq GL2760H NVIDIA Surround / SimXperience AccuForce Pro / Logitech ProtoSimTech PT-2 Pedals / Obutto R3volution / Logitech Z906 5.1 Surround Sound /  Windows 7 64bit Home

Comment: You haven't posted your computer specs. Could you please edit your post so we can assist you better?

Comment: Your display driver is crashing.  Windows 7 and above had a feature to recover from said crashing.  Install a compatible display driver.

Comment: use pastebin website to display your dxdiag results. Also check your minidump folder to see if you have a dump file and/or your memory.dmp and make them available so people can help you... then we'll be able to help you. Hope this helps

Comment: I've since resolved this issue. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My black screen freezes were due to excessive CPU and memory overclocks. I reset my BIOS to defaults and tested Unigine Heaven benchmarks for 10+ hours and it was completely stable. I've tested the affected applications from my original question and they're also stable.

Details: I was overclocking an i7 2600k 3.4Ghz/3.8Ghz Turbo to 4.8Ghz Turbo and, while this was stable for most usages, some scenarios caused crashing such as in GTR2 - FIA GT Racing. Interestingly, other applications, such as iRacing, were very stable, I don't remember crashes like these. These overclocks were also overclocking memory at the same time and this may have been a key factor. I have since been overclocking only the CPU, leaving memory clocks default, and tested every 100Mhz step from 4.8 to 4.2 and 4.2 is where the system became stable, and memtest86+ and Prime95 stress tests also became stable.

Specs after stable: Intel Core i7 2600K @4.2GHz OC / DeepCool GAMMAX 400 CPU Cooler / ASUS P8Z68-V / Corsair Vengeance 16GB DDR3 @1333Mhz MEM / 240GB SSD / Gigabyte G1 Gaming NVIDIA GTX 980 Ti 6GB / 3x Benq GL2760H NVIDIA Surround / SimXperience AccuForce Pro / Logitech ProtoSimTech PT-2 Pedals / Obutto R3volution / Logitech Z906 5.1 Surround Sound / Windows 7 64bit Home